# how to show/hide a div on page1.jsp when a function got success in a page2.jsp using ajax/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

### page1.jsp

```
<html>
    <head>  
<script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    

    </head>  
    <body>
    <form id="registe" action="" novalidate>  
        <input type="hidden" name="txtCaptcha" id="txtCaptcha" value="42988715">        
        <input id="" type="text" name="nam" placeholder="your name"><br>
        <input id="textbox1" type="text" name="name" onchange="showState(this.value)" placeholder="e-mail"/>
        <div id='mailres'>
<!--text from get_mail.jsp-->
        </div>
        <div id='emailcode' style='display:none;'>
<input type="text" name="code" placeholder="code from email">
        </div>
        <input id="" type="text" name="phone" placeholder="phone"/> <br>
        <input id="" type="text" name="city" placeholder="city"/> <br>
    </form>
<script language="javascript">
//Generates the captcha function    
    var a = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9)+ '';
    var b = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9)+ '';       
    var c = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9)+ '';  
    var d = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9)+ '';  
    var e = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9)+ '';
    var f = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9)+ '';     
    var g = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9)+ '';     
    var h = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9)+ '';     

    var code = a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h;
    document.getElementById("txtCaptcha").value = code;
    document.getElementById("txtCaptchaDiv").innerHTML = code;  

// Validate the Entered input aganist the generated security code function   
function ValidCaptcha(){
    var str1 = removeSpaces(document.getElementById('txtCaptcha').value);
    var str2 = removeSpaces(document.getElementById('txtInput').value);
    if (str1 == str2){
        return true;    
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

     function removeSpaces(string){
    return string.split(' ').join('');
}
</script>         
<script language="javascript">  
            var xmlHttp  
            var xmlHttp
            function showState(str){ 
                if (typeof XMLHttpRequest != "undefined"){
                    xmlHttp= new XMLHttpRequest();
                }
                else if (window.ActiveXObject){
                    xmlHttp= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                if (xmlHttp==null){
                    alert ("Browser does not support XMLHTTP Request")
                    return
                } 
                var url="get_mail.jsp";//goes to get_mail.jsp
                url += "?count=" +document.getElementById("textbox1").value;
                url += "&code=" +document.getElementById("txtCaptcha").value;
                xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = stateChange;
                xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
                xmlHttp.send(null);

            }
            function stateChange()
            {   
                if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 || xmlHttp.readyState=="complete"){   
                    document.getElementById("mailres").innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;  

                }   
            }
</script>  
    </body> 
</html>
```

### page2.jsp

```
<%@page import=" java.util.Properties" %>   
<%@page import="javax.mail.BodyPart" %>  
<%@page  import=" javax.mail.Message" %> 
<%@page  import ="javax.mail.MessagingException" %> 
<%@page import ="javax.mail.Multipart" %> 
<%@page import ="javax.mail.SendFailedException" %> 
<%@page import=" javax.mail.Session"  %> 
<%@page import ="javax.mail.Transport"%> 
<%@page import ="javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress"%> 
<%@page import=" javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart" %> 
<%@page import=" javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage"  %> 
<%@page import="javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart" %>  


<html>
<head>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
</head>
<body>
<%
    String s=request.getParameter("count");
    String code = request.getParameter("code");
    if(s.equals("") || s.equals("null"))
    {
        out.println("Please type the email");
    }
    else
    {

        String emailidto= request.getParameter("count");
        String code1 = request.getParameter("code");
        String paswd="password";
        String wrongid="";
        String username="samuel";
        String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        String Password = "*********";
        String from = "*******@gmail.com";
        String toAddress = emailidto;  //Receiver’s email id     
        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
        props.put("mail.smtps.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");

        Session session1 = Session.getInstance(props, null);

        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session1);

        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

        try
        {           

        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddress);

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        message.setSubject("Test Email");

        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

        message.setSubject("Code to complete Enquiry");

        String content = new String("Please copy this code:&nbsp;<h2><span style='color:red;'>"+code1+"</span></h2>"); 

        messageBodyPart.setContent(content, "text/html");

        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

        messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();     

        message.setContent(multipart);

        try 
        {
            Transport tr = session1.getTransport("smtps");
            tr.connect(host, from, Password);
            tr.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());            
            tr.close();
        } 
        catch (SendFailedException sfe) 
        {
              out.println(sfe);
        }
    }
   %>
<!--JSP mail send-->
</body>
</html>
```

I'm making a contact form which send mail to the user when email is typed. So on the 'page1.jsp' the user enters email, then on 'page2.jsp' retrieves the email address and sends to the user for authentication. My question is when the email is send from the 'page2.jsp' I want some trigger to show the hidden div on the 'page1.jsp'.
Here in the hidden div there is a textbox which suppose to be appear when a mail is successfully delivered, so that the user may enter the code by copying from his email .And here the user never see the 'page2.jsp'.

## If understood please help me.

I'm new in this form and got help from 'STACKOVERFLOW' more than a 100 times for my project mainly in JSP.

I've tried and search every where about the above question, but haven't found any.

I believe here there are very talented guru's to help me.

Thanks in advance Guru's.

Comment: What is the meanning of page1.jsp and page 2.jsp are you trying to say that page1 ia opened one tab and p2 is opened in another tab. please clearfy

Comment: I'm making a contact form which send mail to the user when email is typed. So on the 'page1.jsp' the user enters email, then on 'page2.jsp' retrieves the email address and sends to the user for authentication. My question is when the email is send from the 'page2.jsp' I want some trigger to show the hidden div on the 'page1.jsp'. So here the user does not see the 'page2.jsp'. If understood please help me.

Comment: Believe me guys I've tried to post the code but its not displaying properly. I'll even send to email, if you give me so. But please try to help me in getting the code, but not by giving me negative votes?

Comment: its not too hard to post code here.. you have to put 4 spaces in front of each codeline - you even got a preview.. also I don't get why you would return to page1 after you are on page 2 and why page 2 is sending the email - that's some backend logic.. how about making 1 form and submit it via ajax and on success show the div you like to show? no need to have several pages, really..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Review of your code (page1.jsp only):

1. HTML5 Input Types: You have fields like email and phone, and I think you should tell the browser about them - they are not just text inputs. So, for email use type="email" (
2. HTML5 Validation: You should make 2 validations - in the client side, so you can tell the user that he inserts non-email or non-tel values, and in the server-side: before you use the data you should check that the phone is a real telephone number, etc. For the client side you can use the html5 validation, raw js validation or get some plugin for the validation.
3. You tried to get the #txtInput element's value by JS (document.getElementById('txtInput').value), but there is no element with this id. Also, you can't make such CAPTCHA tests: CAPTCHA is an image that a computer can't read and this is text. The fact that the CAPTCHA value is generated in the client side tells you that the computers can see it. I suggest using recaptcha or any other test.
4. Accessibility: I suggest you to add  tags, html title attributes , and you must add a "send" button.
5. You wrote:

   var xmlHttp
   var xmlHttp
   But I think it's just a mistake.
6. I don't think you should deal with ActiveXObject, it's for really old IE browsers..
7. You've imported JQUERY but you haven't used it - think if you want to use JQUERY or raw JS for the AJAX.
8. Instead of xmlHttp.send(null) you can write xmlHttp.send()
9. Instead of if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 || xmlHttp.readyState=="complete") you should write if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
10. In your titles in this post you called the second file page2.jsp but in the code I see get_mail.jsp. Check it.

So There are several things that you can change - 1,2,4,6,7,8, but 3,5,9,10 are important things that you should fix. Also, there is a new HTML5 functions of AJAX but I will not write of them since it is your (probably) first time of writing AJAX app and because there are many browsers which are not support it. Also, if it really your first time of writing AJAX, I suggest you not to use JQUERY. Any way, good luck!

UPDATE:

in the second jsp file (which sends the mail), end in the end of the last try a "OK" print to the page (out.println("OK")). Now, on the first file, in the if block in the stateChange function, add an if statement that checks if the xmlHttp.responseText is "OK" (Remove this line : document.getElementById("mailres").innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText). if it is ok, you can do whatever you want - it will be done only if the mail was sent.

You can change the visibility of the div like this:

```
document.getElementById("emailcode").style.display = "block";
```

Comment: +1 @RanSch for your suggestion. I'll definitely use the ajax accordingly as you suggested. As I'm a newbie I got to learn more AJAX. Thanks for your time and effort. I really respect that.

Comment: Read carefully my answer. If it is helpful, mark it as the best answer so people will recognize it fast. if If it isn't tell me and I will se what I can do.

Comment: everything in the code is working fine, my only requirement is how to make the <div id='emailcode' style='display:none;'> on page1.jsp display, only when email is send from the page2.jsp(I mean get_mail.jsp) ?@RanSch

Comment: See the update in this answer. If it's fine, mark it. If it's not, write the code / tell us until it would be fine.

Comment: function stateChange(){if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 || xmlHttp.readyState==200){if(xmlHttp.responseText=="OK"){document.getElementById("emailcode").style.display = "block";}} As you have suggested I have used this code and placed out.println("OK"); in the try statement in page2.jsp. What's happening is page2.jsp is sending the mail but still, I;m not able to display the hidden div. Any suggestions please, I really appreciate your help Mr.RanSch. Once again thanks for your valuable time. Sorry to say 'still not solved'.

Comment: If you can't see the hidden div, you probably don't get the "OK" response text. Maybe you got "ok" with some spaces...write an else block in this if statement: alert(xmlHttp.responseText). Or you can use console...Tell us what you get.

Comment: In the alert '<html><body>OK</body></html>'. This is what I'm getting. Any Suggestions please..@RanSch.

Comment: Remove all the tags from the second file except the jsp tags.
and if it still won't work add trim() : xmlHttp.responseText.trim(). It it will work remove the alert or change it to console.error and mark this answer.

Comment: SUPERB, EXCELLENT MAN! JUST EXACTLY WHAT I WANT. THANK YOU SO MUCH. YOU ARE THE REAL-GURU @RanSch.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use AJAX. AJAX enables communication after the page was loaded, so you don't have to load the whole page again. There are many tutorials for ajax, one of them is on W3schools.

Ajax is not a new language, it is written on JS and it will work like this:

1. The user typed his mail.
2. You validate the mail and if it's fine you send an AJAX call to the server. If the mail is fine, send the mail and return a good response (like "OK").
3. The page with the email gets the response and according to it, the hidden part is shown.

I don't know what do you know but I suggest you to learn AJAX and ask us when something is not clear.

Comment: Thank you @RanSch for your reply, I've just updated my code, will you please check this code and give me your valuable reply?

Comment: I wrote you a new answer with the review. Good luck!